# Mapped data not being read by react-scroll

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-scroll

On this Image, you can see I made some data to be passed on.

[NavbarData.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSizT.png)

And i passed it by using the .map function and populate it on the to={} property

[Navbar.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHcWy.png)

Im getting this error

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')"

even though i passed the data on the to={} property

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGgkj.png)

You can check this snippet for reference.

[Styled Components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1im8Y.png)

Comment: Navbar.js file shows a stylesheet

Comment: @PulsaraSandeepa It is a styled components.

Comment: Hi @JohnPaulPineda, welcome to SO, to help you with your problem or future questions please consider sharing your code into code snippets instead of images, please check [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score -1):

I forgot to pass the to={} property
on the react-router-dom Link[image]